# Gzip outputting the incorrect ratios

Tags: npm, terminal, gzip

I have this script to build and gzip.

`vite build && gzip -9 -r dist && gzip -l -r dist`

This is the output of the last command `gzip -l -r dist`

```
         compressed        uncompressed  ratio uncompressed_name
            300                 429  36.8% dist/index.html
          11580               28960  60.1% dist/assets/axios-4a70c6fc.js
          30689              231919  86.8% dist/assets/index-702c97b5.css
            298                 370  29.5% dist/assets/Errors-eb686dfd.js
            866                1699  51.3% dist/assets/Account-ec34f921.js
          56906              163998  65.3% dist/assets/index-d1408528.js
            787                1492  49.7% dist/assets/Login-ed6a096f.js
            177                 171  19.3% dist/assets/data_key-79cb74cc.js
          11356               29396  61.5% dist/assets/Signup-ace602f3.js
```

The problem being the ratios are wrong. if I run the command `gzip -l -r dist` immediately after I get this.

```
  compressed uncompressed  ratio uncompressed_name
     300          429  30.0% dist/index.html
   11580        28960  60.0% dist/assets/axios-4a70c6fc.js
   30689       231919  86.7% dist/assets/index-702c97b5.css
     298          370  19.4% dist/assets/Errors-eb686dfd.js
     866         1699  49.0% dist/assets/Account-ec34f921.js
   56906       163998  65.3% dist/assets/index-d1408528.js
     787         1492  47.3% dist/assets/Login-ed6a096f.js
     177          171  -3.0% dist/assets/data_key-79cb74cc.js
   11356        29396  61.3% dist/assets/Signup-ace602f3.js
```

I have tried to put a sleep statement in the line in case for some reason it was a timed delay to get the correct results.

`vite build && gzip -9 -r dist && echo 'Wait...' && sleep 10 && gzip -l -r dist`

This as expected did not change the output, this was more of a sanity check.

I fail to understand why this is happening. I believe I am missing information or not understanding something.

Version of gzip `Apple gzip 353.100.22`

Comment: Please don’t post terminal output as images, paste it as monospaced text.

Comment: @pzkpfw I have made this change.

Comment: What version of gzip? (Do `gzip --version`.)

Comment: @MarkAdler `Apple gzip 353.100.22`

Comment: Your script must be using a different `PATH`, and running a different gzip. Try running `gzip --version` in the script.

Comment: You can also run `which gzip` on both your command line and in the script to see which binary is being used in each case.

Comment: @MarkAdler this does seem to be the problem! one is using `/opt/homebrew/bin/gzip` and the one with correct math is `/usr/bin/gzip` I uninstalled the brew version with `brew uninstall gzip` and now it works correctly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using two different gzip executables due to a different `PATH` being used in the script vs. the command line. The first one is normal gzip, which is computing the compression of the compressed data, without the gzip header and trailer. The second is Apple's version, which includes the gzip header and trailer overhead in the calculation. In the former case, 18 bytes plus the length of the file name (which in this case is the name that follows `dist/`) and a terminating zero byte are subtracted from the file size, where what remains is the size of the actual compressed data. That size is used in the calculation instead of the .gz file size.

Which one is right? It's a matter of taste.